# Python list to string spacing

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list such as this

```
list = ['Hi', ',', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'Bob', '!']
```

I wanted to convert this to a string, and originally, I found on stackoverflow that .join() could be used. So i did:

```
x = ' '.join(list)
print(x)
```

which prints

```
"Hi , my name is Bob !"
```

when what I want printed is:

```
"Hi, my name is Bob!"
```

How do I not add spaces before periods and exclamation points? I want a more general case so that I can for example read in a text file as a list, and convert it to a string.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this the actual representation of your list: `["Hi", ",", "my", "name", "is", "Bob", "!"]`?

Comment: Also, you're going to have a bad time with your code if you use `list` as an argument name for your *list*. It shadows the [built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) `list`.

Comment: *"read in a text file as a list, and convert it to a string"* - Why would you do that?

Comment: use regex on list with join method.

Comment: That was just pseudocode. I'm just trying to understand how to tackle this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this, using simple regex?

```
import re

list = ['Hi', ',', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'Bob', '!']
x = re.sub(r' (\W)',r'\1',' '.join(list))
print(x)

>>> Hi, my name is Bob!
```

Answer (score 2):

To solve it in a general case, use the `nltk`'s ["moses" detokenizer](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/1282):

```
In [1]: l = ["Hi", ",", "my", "name", "is", "Bob", "!"]

In [2]: from nltk.tokenize.moses import MosesDetokenizer

In [3]: detokenizer = MosesDetokenizer()

In [4]: detokenizer.detokenize(l, return_str=True)
Out[4]: u'Hi, my name is Bob!'
```

The detokenizer is not yet a part of a stable `nltk` package. To be able to use it now, install `nltk` directly from github.

Answer (score 0):

A little different solution:

```
>>> from string import punctuation
>>> lis = ["Hi", ",", "my", "name", "is", "Bob", "!"]
>>> string = ''
>>> for i, x in enumerate(lis):
        if x not in punctuation and i != 0:
            string += ' ' + x
        elif x not in punctuation and i == 0:
            string += x
        else:
            string += x
>>> print(string)
"Hi, my name is Bob!"
```